# Excel - how to differ same two values but with different reference

Tags: excel

I have cells in column A that reference to either
B column from same sheet or B column from Sheet2.

For example: A1 = B1 and B1 = 5. So A1 = 5.

And I have that A2 = Sheet2!B2 and Sheet2!B2 = 5. So A2 = 5.

So I need to differ those two 5's in A column so I can use it another formula. 
(For example if 5 from "Sheet2" then do this.)

I can't use VBA, and it's excel 2007.
Those values that reference to Sheet2 are also bold with red font,
but it doesn't help me a lot cause I can't use VBA.

Comment: 'Differ those two..."? Huh... What difference does font/color make? If you mean I need to resolve different formulas based on a value then you can use IF so cell=IF(A1=0,1,2). If A1 had value of 0 put 1 in cell otherwise put 2 in. Is that what you are after. Something like that? You can nest IF's as well if there are more than 2 permutations of results.

Comment: So UDF is also not possible?

Comment: Maybe I phrased the question wrong. It has nothing to do with 5's. It was just an example.Maybe it should've been: Can I do anything with the text of the formula. For example if I could get Left_of_formula(A2;6) it would return "sheet2", cause formula in cell A2 is "Sheet2!B2"

Answer (score 0):

Just do the test:

```
=CHOOSE(COUNTIF(A1:A2,5)+1,"neither",IF(A1=5,"from this sheet","from other sheet"),"both")
```

or

```
=CHOOSE(2*(A2=5)+(A1=5)+1,"neither","this sheet","other sheet","both")
```

Comment: Yeah, I know "choose" function. Maybe I phrased the question wrong. It has nothing to do with 5's. It was just an example.Maybe it should've been: Can I do anything with the text of the formula. For example if I could get Left_of_formula(A2;6) it would return "sheet2", cause formula in cell A2 is "Sheet2!B2"